# Does Quickblox IOS sdk support all below options?

Tags: ios, quickblox

Does Quickblox IOS sdk support all below options?

1. One to One message with online users.
2. Sender is online and Receiver is in background then alert message.
3. Sender is online and Receiver is offline then push notification alert to receiver.
4. Sync all Chat history and offline messages. When again installed app.
5. Count of unread messages.

Anyone had used these services?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, is supports everything that you've listed. I'm using it in a project as we speak.